# Run script with the use of RegisterClientScriptBlock into with Angularjs page Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to inject script with `RegisterClientScriptBlock`:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "script", "<script>console.log('Test')</script>", false)
```

and its not working - i don't see the "Test" message in the console log

- do i need to use an angular event that will be a point in the life cycle?
  like Jquery `document.ready()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your script string is not quoted properly. Just to test the theory, change the double quote to single

```
"<script>console.log('Test')</script>"
```

Comment: Thanks! but it was just a typo - i fixed it in the post, in the code it's alright